# how to remove this error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select sum((
SELECT 
SUM (gb.period_net_dr - gb.period_net_cr) "PTD" 
FROM gl_balances gb, gl_code_combinations gcc 
WHERE 
    gb.period_name = NVL(:P_PERIOD,gb.period_name)
AND gb.currency_code = (SELECT currency_code FROM gl_ledgers WHERE ledger_id = gb.ledger_id) 
AND gcc.segment4 =(select FLEX_VALUE from FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL where description ='Pass Through Costs To Be Realised')
AND gb.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id) 
+
(SELECT 
SUM (gb.period_net_dr - gb.period_net_cr) "PTD" 
FROM gl_balances gb, gl_code_combinations gcc 
WHERE 
    gb.period_name = NVL(:P_PERIOD,gb.period_name)
AND gb.currency_code = (SELECT currency_code FROM gl_ledgers WHERE ledger_id = gb.ledger_id) 
AND gcc.segment4 =(select FLEX_VALUE from FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL where description ='Pass Through Costs Realised')
AND gb.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id)) as Total_Pass_Through_Costs
from
dual)
(select sum((
SELECT 
SUM (gb.period_net_dr - gb.period_net_cr) "PTD" 
FROM gl_balances gb, gl_code_combinations gcc 
WHERE 
    gb.period_name = NVL(:P_PERIOD,gb.period_name)
AND gb.currency_code = (SELECT currency_code FROM gl_ledgers WHERE ledger_id = gb.ledger_id) 
AND gcc.segment4 =(select FLEX_VALUE from FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL where description ='Services Billing')
AND gb.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id) 
+
(SELECT 
SUM (gb.period_net_dr - gb.period_net_cr) "PTD" 
FROM gl_balances gb, gl_code_combinations gcc 
WHERE 
    gb.period_name = NVL(:P_PERIOD,gb.period_name)
AND gb.currency_code = (SELECT currency_code FROM gl_ledgers WHERE ledger_id = gb.ledger_id) 
AND gcc.segment4 =(select FLEX_VALUE from FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL where description ='pass Through Billing')
AND gb.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id)) as Total_Billing
from
dual
```

How to remove this error
(java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended)

Comment: when do you get the error ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: That's several, separate queries...

Comment: I get Two This (Total_Billing,Total_Pass_Through_Costs).

Comment: I get Two This (Total_Billing,Total_Pass_Through_Costs).This qury is run.but data is not come .That Time show this error (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended)

Comment: What is supposed to be happening between the `dual` on on line 19 (which is the one the error is against) and the opening parenthesis on the next line? Maybe you meant that to be `dual)+`, but then you're missing another closing parenthesis later. Your parentheses seem to be a bit of a mess throughout though, so start by breaking it down and figuring out what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 brakets which do not have pairs:

- 1st is not opened anywhere
- 2nd is not closed anywhere

Can you check the brakets from the string:

```
...
from
dual)
(select sum...
```

they do not seem to be opened/closed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the actual error in your query wont make the answer to this useful to anyone else searching for answers.

However, some (obvious) tips for finding this sort of issue might be useful.

So . . .

- Edit your query into something nicely structured (problems sometimes just jump out at you)
- Indent appropriately and put brackets for sub-queries on a separate line and line them up vertically.
- Use an editor that highlights matching brackets

Fixing this kind of error is a basic skill that coders will need to learn for themselves for almost any language.